# How to output a 'run-time error' of a program ran by execvp function into a file?

Tags: c, linux, fork, execvp, dup2

I'm writing a program on eclipse, linux, in which I need to output the results of an inner program `a.out`(ran by `execvp()`) function, into a file(I'm using execvp function, but every other `exec` function is good).

The program runs flawlessly for proper input, and outputs into the file I defined.

The problem is that I need to output every output, even errors (run-time errors, like segFault) message that will be received for input that'll cause the inner program `a.out` to fail (e.g. divide by zero).

here is my code for the program that call to `execvp`:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main() {
    //string for execvp to run "a.out"
    char *arg[] = {"./a.out", NULL};
    //name of input file
    char *input = "input.txt";
    pid_t child_pid;
    int child_status;
    int input_fd, fd_output;
    //open input.txt
    if ((input_fd = open(input, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    {
        perror("");
        exit(-1);
    }
    //redirect standard input to input.txt
    dup2(input_fd, 0);
    //create output.txt
    if ((fd_output = open("output.txt",
            O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_RDWR, 0644)) < 0)
    {
        perror("");
        exit(-1);
    }
    //redirect standard output and standard error to output.txt
    dup2(fd_output, 1);
    dup2(fd_output, 2);

    child_pid = fork();
    if(child_pid == 0) {
        // This is done by the child process.
        execvp(arg[0], arg);

        // If execvp returns, it must have failed.
        perror("fork");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        // This is run by the parent. Wait for the child to terminate.
        if (wait(&child_status) == -1) {
            printf("error!\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`a.out` source file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main () {
    int op, num1, num2;
    do {
        printf("Please enter operation\r\n");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        switch(op) {
        case 1:
            printf("Please enter two numbers\r\n");
            scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
            printf("The devision is %d\r\n", num1/num2);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Bye\r\n");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }while(op != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

good `input.txt':

```
1
3 4
4
```

bad `input.txt:

```
1
3 0
4
```

for the good input, I get `output.txt`:

```
Please enter operation
Please enter two numbers
The devision is 0
Please enter operation
Bye
```

but for the bad output I get a blank output.txt file, no matter what.
So how to output `a.out` errors (if there's any) into output.txt?

Comment: What if you just run the `a.out` with bad input manually?

Comment: You must perdrform the `dup2(  fd_output, {1.2]});` only for the child program ( := **after** the fork() ). In your program, stdout and stderr are also redirected for the parent process.

Comment: @EugeneSh., manually, `a.out` prints something like: `segmentation fault (core dumped)` to the terminal/console. @joop , first of all, if it's true, how come I get (for the good input) the good output into `output.txt`? In addition, how can I perform your suggestion? simply put the `dup2` function right below `fork()`?

Comment: OK I just tried your suggestion and put the i/o redirection after the fork, just above `execvp`. It didn't work. The exact output for the error (when I ran it manually) is: `Floating point exception (core dumped)`.